# Delete List with same property

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of object.
Every object has 3 properties.
Is there a good way to check get the double objects where the properties are identical.

```
var upperT = dimensionList.GroupBy(x => x.UpperMetricToleranceValue).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
var sizeT = dimensionList.GroupBy(x => x.ComputedSize).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
var lowerT = dimensionList.GroupBy(x => x.LowerMetricToleranceValue).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

foreach (var dimension in dimensionList)
{
    foreach (var upper in upperT)
    {
        foreach (var lower in sizeT)
        {
            foreach (var size in lowerT)
            {
                if (DELETE HERE IF SAME)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I don't think this is a good method to use this.
I don't want to use 3rd party libraries like moreLinq

Comment: You can try to `Round` the values before grouping; i.e. if `5.998 ~ 6.001` you can put `GroupBy(x => Math.Round(x * 100)).First()`; note that when `double` contains integer value we don' have rounding errors

Comment: If the data are stored in a RDBMS, it's likely to be much more efficient to use SQL to delete the items than to use quadropoly nested loops.

Comment: The question is very unclear as it's written It seems like you just need to group by a composite key. `demensionList.GroupBy(x => new { x.UpperMetricToleranceValue, x.ComputedSize, x.LowerMetricToleranceValue}`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of grouping using a single property, use the three properties at once:

```
var unique = dimensionList.GroupBy(x => new {UpperMetricToleranceValue=x.UpperMetricToleranceValue, ComputedSize=x.ComputedSize, LowerMetricToleranceValue=x.LowerMetricToleranceValue}).Select(g => g.First());
```

Comment: why use a tuple and not just an anonymous type

Comment: Yeah, why not. Will reflect that.

Comment: Perfect, as a side note, using anonymous should be more versatile, because If the OP decided to do this in EF instead Tuple wouldn't be supported

Comment: @johnny5 Thanks for the comments.